# Disable Chars in TextBox

Tags: java, android

Is there a possibility to disable some Inputs like Spacebar, Linebreak etc. in an TextView / TextBox?

Comment: I think this might be of some use : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to limit input into an EditText.

Foremost among them is setting the android:inputType.  List of options [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).

You can also set a TextWatcher.  Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).